Configuring IP Routes / Default Gateways
I work at a location where we have to wear multiple hats, I've been tasked with extending certain VLANs to another location. The configuration below appears to be working, but I don't know enough to know if I've followed best practices.
Ideally, I would like DIST1 and DIST2 to perform inter-VLAN routing, anything outside of their known VLANs should route to 10.0.0.1. I'm not sure if this is working exactly as I hoped, I believe everything is hitting the gateway defined on DIST1 before jumping VLANs, maybe this is required behavior?
With regards to ACCESS1 and ACCESS2, should the default gateway be DIST1 or DIST2? Does the gateway defined impact client traffic or is it just for the management interface? Similarly for client devices attached to ACCESS1 and ACCESS2, should I be setting the default gateway of the network adapter to DIST1 or DIST2?
Would it also be appropriate to disable ip proxy-arp?
hostname DIST1

int vlan1
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0

int vlan10
 ip address 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0

int vlan11
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1

hostname DIST2 // Connected to DIST1 via trunk port

int vlan1
 ip address 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.0

int vlan10
 ip address 172.16.0.2 255.255.255.0

int vlan11
 ip address 172.16.1.2 255.255.255.0

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.2

hostname ACCESS1 // Connected to DIST2 via access port.

int vlan10
 ip address 172.16.0.3 255.255.255.0

ip default-gateway 172.16.0.1

hostname ACCESS2 // Connected to DIST2 via access port.

int vlan11
 ip address 172.16.1.3 255.255.255.0

ip default-gateway 172.16.1.1



Since your VLANs run all the way through to DIST1/2 you should use their IP addresses as gateways (assuming they‘re layer3 with routing enabled).

should the default gateway be DIST1 or DIST2?

Either. Since there's no redundancy protocol, there's no fallback.

Would it also be appropriate to disable ip proxy-arp?

Do not use proxy ARP unless you know what you're doing and there's a very good reason to do so (usually temporary for migration).

Are there any implications between selecting DIST1 vs DIST2 as the default gateway? I suspect if I set the gateways to DIST1, traffic will travel through DIST2 to get to DIST1 before jumping to another VLAN, do I have that correct?

Yes, depending on the topology that you haven't shown us, L2 forwarding may cross DIST2 before reaching the L3 gateway in DIST1, or vice versa.

I've added a diagram, if a device on VLAN10 needs to communicate with a device on VLAN 11, I assume that traffic is going through the gateway on DIST1? Is there a way to route through DIST2? If not, are the interfaces defined on DIST2 of any benefit or have I simply created extra management interfaces?

The gateway an end node uses depends on the end node's configuration. Just configure whatever you like better.
